# to identify if the same user has downloaded paid app on different devices in iOS9

Tags: ios, ios9

I need to track if the same user(same iTunes account) has downloaded the app on different devices so that I can show them the same data without having them to login again on the app on the second device. is there a way to identify the user?

Comment: Back end  database to store and query user details?  iCloud? There are many different ways and services to achieve this.

Comment: If you use CloudKit or iCloud to store data and the user is logged into iCloud then data will be available on all of their devices, but if they aren't logged in to iCloud then you can't know; you will need them to create an account.

Comment: is there a way to know the user logged into iTunes so that I can save their id in my DB? is apple sharing any unique info of the user who is downloading which can be saved in Db?